# Asp.net core Protect Folder out side wwwroot

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-5

I am creating an asp.net core app and using .Net5. I am uploading files outside www-root folder. Here is my configuration for the directory.

```
 app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(@$"{Configuration["AppConfiguration:PhysicalDirectoryBasePath"]}"),
                RequestPath = new PathString("/app-data"),
                EnableDirectoryBrowsing = false
            });
```

I want to secure that folder so that no public user can access it. I want to check the header before accessing file like

```
header contains app-token then allow file to access otherwise not
```

I am unable to stop file accessing for public users. How to achieve this?

Comment: one solution is to remove the above code form startup.cs file and then serve file via the controller. But there are many kind of files like html, js and images . How to handle all those files?

Comment: Just add a controller action that sends the file down the wire, `return File(path);`

Comment: dont you think it will expose my physical path from the system?

Comment: Nope, that would protect your file system, you will have to identity the file somehow, I wouldnt send the "path" as a route parameter.

Comment: Ok got it. this way I can check the context header as well? correct?

Comment: Can you tell me how to accept file name as a route? like index.html or script.js?

Comment: Why would you protect those files in the first place? If you just want to make sure, that no unauthorized user can access those files, you just need to make sure you call `.UseAuhtorization()` before `.UseStaticFiles()` and make sure you have a fallback provider specified. Details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-5.0#static-file-authorization

Comment: I am building a course library that can be run on LMS. So when the user launches the course the files must be served. But I want to use some header so that only those can access files who sent that header. otherwise not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) for this. Namely [Map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) allows to execute required middleware for a path

```
app.Map("/app-data", appBuilder =>
{
    appBuilder.UseFilter();

    appBuilder.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider($@"{Configuration["AppConfiguration:PhysicalDirectoryBasePath"]}"),
        RequestPath = new PathString(""), //empty, because root path is in Map now
        EnableDirectoryBrowsing = false
    });
}
```

Filter middleware

```
public class FilterMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public FilterMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext.Request.Headers["API-KEY"] == "secret key")
        {
            //proceed serving files
            await _next(httpContext);
        }
        else
        {
            //return you custom response
            await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync("Forbidden");
        }
    }
}
```

Extension class allows to call `UseFilter`

```
public static class FilterMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseFilter(this IApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder)
    {
        return applicationBuilder.UseMiddleware<FilterMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok so do i need to keep the code in my question or shall i remove that code and use middleware only?

Comment: @HaseebKhan You need to replace your code with the first code snippet in my answer. Which is `app.Map( { appBuilder.UseFilter(); appBuilder.UseFileServer(...); })`

Comment: Ok I am checking now.

Comment: your solution is perfectly working. Thanks man

Comment: one issue i am facing is when my path contains .zip file the middleware let it pass. I don't know why but even debugger does not hit

Comment: @HaseebKhan What exact url with .zip gives this behaviour?

Comment: my normal files url is www.test.com/app-data/content/abc.html and my zip file url is www.test.com/app-data/courses/abc.zip

Comment: @HaseebKhan It doesn't pass through, if you download the file you will see it has different content then original one (most likely it is 'Forbidden' in your case if you haven't changed the text). So protection works perfectly fine, you just need to tune the response with some headers probably or different status code

Comment: @HaseebKhan It is just browser behaves this way, so it suggests you to download a file if its extension is .zip

Comment: The solution I have found is I was creating a fileserver for the whole directory which contains multiple directories. Like E:\\application-data this specific directory in the hard drive contains multiple more directories like content, courses etc. and the file server middleware called before authentication and authorization. So that's why my zip file path was passing through. So changed the file server path and which does not contain the zip files folder. This way i can protect zip file downloading for public user. it can only work for my application now